# Syncing podcasts between devices

Tags: ios, ipad, ipod, podcasts

I watch video podcasts on my iPad and listen to audio podcasts on my iPod.  Both podcasts sync to each device.  If I delete audio podcast from iPad, I lose it on the iPod as well and vice-versa.

How can I stop this from occurring?  I don't have enough space on the iPad for all the audio podcasts, and can only download one or two episodes of the video podcasts for all the room the audio podcasts take up.

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes, select your iPad, select Podcasts, then select "Automatically include (smaller number) episodes of (selected podcasts or all podcasts)"

For your iPod you can set it to all or a larger number.

Alternatively you can manually sync your iPad's podcast episodes in the same location.